# MySql 2 DataAdapters fill error - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: mysql, multithreading, fill

Trying to retrieve data from 2 tables of my MySQL DB to 2 gridviews on from load.

```
private const string connStr = "Server=myServer;Database=myDb;Uid=user;Pwd=pw;";

private void MainPage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread load_product = new Thread(ProductLoad);
            Thread load_costs = new Thread(CostLoad);
            load_costs.Start();
            load_product.Start();
        }

public void ProductLoad()
        {
            MySqlConnection prConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            MySqlDataAdapter daProduct = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY idProduct DESC LIMIT 100", prConn);
            DataSet dsPr = new DataSet();
            daProduct.Fill(ds);
            gridProducts.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {

                gridProducts.DataSource = dsPr.Tables[0];

            }
                ));
        }

public void CostLoad()
        {
            MySqlConnection costConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
            MySqlDataAdapter daCost = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM costs ORDER BY idCost DESC LIMIT 100", costConn);
            DataSet dsCost = new DataSet();
            **daCost.Fill(dsCost);** // I get error at this point or at another Fill operation (System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'
)
            gridProducts.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => {

                gridCost.DataSource = dsCost.Tables[0];

            }
                ));
        }
```

Trying to retrieve data from 2 tables of my MySQL DB to 2 gridviews on from load. When loading only 1 table it works. But it shows an error when trying to call 2 threads.